# append used in different versions of scipy

Tags: python, scipy, append

I have questions with regards to the function of append in different versions of scipy. If I used the following script in the Python 2.7.3 and scipy 0.10.1 (numpy1.6.2), everything works out well.

```
a=(1,2,3);b=(4,5,6);append(a,b,1);array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
a=[];b=(4,5,6);append(a,b,1);array([4,5,6])
```

But if I run these in the python2.7 and scipy1.0.0 (numpy 1.13.3):

```
a=(1,2,3);b=(4,5,6);append(a,b,1);
a=[];b=(4,5,6);append(a,b,1);
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in    File
>   `"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py"`,
>   line 5152, in append
>       `return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)` numpy.core._internal.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of
>   dimension 1

But I have checked the functions of append in the function_base.py, they are identical in both version of numpy. Do you guys know why this would happen?

Another question is that if I am using python2.7, it is possible for me to use an older version of scipy/numpy installed under python2.6?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Python has a list `append` **method**.  `numpy` has an `append` **function**.  If you `import numpy as np`, then you use it as `np.append`.  But you shouldn't use it.  You should learn to use `np.concatenate`, adjusting array dimensions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is off, but here's my guess as to what you do

```
a=(1,2,3)
b=(4,5,6)
append(a,b,1)
# array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

`a` and `b` are tuples.

If I use the `np.append` function:

```
In [566]: np.append(a,b)
Out[566]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

With `axis=0` this also works; with `axis=1` I get an error, because `a` has only one dimension.  If an older version of `np.append` works with `axis=1` it's because there's a bug and it is ignoring the axis parameter.  (the newer versions are right; you shouldn't try to use old versions just to allow `axis=1`.)

I use `import numpy as np`, not `from numpy import *`.  That way it's clear when I use `numpy` functions. (numpy underlies scipy as well).

What we should really be doing is:

```
In [569]: np.concatenate((a,b))
Out[569]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

This turns both `a` and `b` into 1d arrays, and then joins them along the only axis, to make a new array.

Same thing works if `a` is this empty list:

```
a=[]
b=(4,5,6)
append(a,b,1)
# array([4,5,6])
```

This `a` is a list, and does have an `append` method

```
In [570]: a=[]
In [571]: a.append(b)
In [572]: a
Out[572]: [(4, 5, 6)]
```

and an `extend`:

```
In [573]: a=[]
In [574]: a.extend(b)
In [575]: a
Out[575]: [4, 5, 6]
```

Stay away from `np.append`.  It confuses beginners all the time.  Stick with list append, and `np.concatenate`.

`np.append` and `np.stack` are also useful for joining arrays (or lists).

When creating an array iteratively, it is best to append to lists and make the array at the end:

```
alist = []
for i in range(5):
   alist.append(i)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

Repeated list append is good practice.  Repeated array concatenate is slower.